# avoid scatterplot between the same variable in a loop

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2

I have a data frame (tab3) looking like this:

```
 CWRES ID  AGE  BMI  WGT
3     0.59034000  1 37.5 20.7 64.6
4     1.81300000  1 37.5 20.7 64.6
5     1.42920000  1 37.5 20.7 64.6
6     0.59194000  1 37.5 20.7 64.6
7     0.30886000  1 37.5 20.7 64.6
8    -0.14601000  1 37.5 20.7 64.6
9    -0.19776000  1 37.5 20.7 64.6
10    0.74208000  1 37.5 20.7 64.6
11   -0.69280000  1 37.5 20.7 64.6
38   -2.42900000  1 37.5 20.7 64.6
39   -0.25732000  1 37.5 20.7 64.6
40   -0.49689000  1 37.5 20.7 64.6
41   -0.11556000  1 37.5 20.7 64.6
42    0.91036000  1 37.5 20.7 64.6
43   -0.24766000  1 37.5 20.7 64.6
44   -0.14962000  1 37.5 20.7 64.6
45   -0.45651000  1 37.5 20.7 64.6
48    0.53237000  2 58.5 23.0 53.4
49   -0.53284000  2 58.5 23.0 53.4
50   -0.33086000  2 58.5 23.0 53.4
51   -0.56355000  2 58.5 23.0 53.4
52    0.00883120  2 58.5 23.0 53.4
53   -1.00650000  2 58.5 23.0 53.4
80    0.85810000  2 58.5 23.0 53.4
81   -0.71715000  2 58.5 23.0 53.4
82    0.44346000  2 58.5 23.0 53.4
83    1.09890000  2 58.5 23.0 53.4
84    0.98726000  2 58.5 23.0 53.4
85    0.19667000  2 58.5 23.0 53.4
86   -1.32570000  2 58.5 23.0 53.4
89   -4.56920000  3 43.5 26.7 66.2
90    0.75174000  3 43.5 26.7 66.2
91    0.40935000  3 43.5 26.7 66.2
92    0.18340000  3 43.5 26.7 66.2
93    0.27399000  3 43.5 26.7 66.2
94   -0.23596000  3 43.5 26.7 66.2
95   -1.59460000  3 43.5 26.7 66.2
96   -0.03708900  3 43.5 26.7 66.2
97    0.68750000  3 43.5 26.7 66.2
98   -0.47979000  3 43.5 26.7 66.2
125   2.23200000  3 43.5 26.7 66.2
126   0.90470000  3 43.5 26.7 66.2
127  -0.34493000  3 43.5 26.7 66.2
128  -0.02114400  3 43.5 26.7 66.2
129  -1.08830000  3 43.5 26.7 66.2
130  -0.33937000  3 43.5 26.7 66.2
131   1.19820000  3 43.5 26.7 66.2
132   0.81653000  3 43.5 26.7 66.2
133   1.61810000  3 43.5 26.7 66.2
134   0.42914000  3 43.5 26.7 66.2
135  -1.03150000  3 43.5 26.7 66.2
```

...

I want to plot the variable CWRES versus ID, AGE, BMI and WGT. To do this I use this code:

```
library(ggplot2)
plotloop <- function(x, na.rm = TRUE, ...) {
  nm <- names(x)
  for (i in seq_along(nm)) {
    print(ggplot(x,aes_string(x = nm[i], y = nm[1])) + 
            geom_point()) }
}
plotloop(tab3)
```

However, it also plots CWRES vs CWRES and I do not want to plot CWRES vs CWRES.

What should I do?

Thanks in advance,

Mario

Answer (score 0):

The loop may not be the best way to go about plotting multiple plots with ggplot. Hence I will not try to fix your code but suggest an alternative route.

You should first melt your data.frame to transform it to long format with only retaining the CWRES variable:

```
require(reshape2)
mDf <- melt(x, c("CWRES"))
```

Now you can create your plots as follows:

```
g <- ggplot(mDF,aes(x=CWRES,y=value))
g <- g + geom_point()
g <- g + facet_grid(.~variable)
g
```

This creates a faceted plot with the four scatter plots next to each other.

If you really want to plot multiple i would proceed as follows (based on the formatting above):

```
variables <- unique(mDF$variable)
for (v in variables)
{
print(ggplot(mDF[mDF$variable==v,],aes(x=CWRES,y=value)) + geom_point() )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I really do not want to use facets_grid(). I want an independent plot in each page, something like what I obtain but without the first plot (CWRES vs CWRES). Thanks,

Comment: Added an extension. As a hacky alternative you could in principle just include an if not CWRES construct in your code.

Answer (score -1):

Finally I found the solution:

This code works great!

```
for(i in names(tab3)[2:5]) {
  df2 <- tab3[, c(i, "CWRES")]
  print(ggplot(tab3) + geom_point(aes_string(x = i, y = "CWRES")) + theme_bw())
}
```

Comment: This answer lack basic explanation: what was essential part of problem, how solution work. It look like someone give you a code and you pasted it here. Beside variable names don't match and logic of code is different which don't help either.